# Updating session variables kick user to login page or not?

Tags: session, authentication, coldfusion, session-scope, userinfo

I'm developing new application and using session variables to store some of the users information like email, permission level, etc. I'm wondering once user decide to update lets say email or permissions for themselves that won't affect right away. Session variables will be updated only if they logout and then login again. I know that one way to avoid this would be to update existing session variables. Here is my code example of what I'm setting in session variables upon users login:

```
<cfset local.appStruct = structNew()>
<cfset structInsert(local.appStruct, "SysAdmin", checkUser.SystemAdmin, true)>
<cfset structInsert(local.appStruct, "UserName", checkUser.UserName, true)>
<cfset structInsert(local.appStruct, "AccountID", checkUser.AccountID, true)>
<cfset structInsert(local.appStruct, "Email", checkUser.Email, true)>
<cfset structInsert(local.appStruct, "TempPW", checkUser.TempPassword, true)>
<cfset structInsert(local.appStruct, "AccessType", permissionType, true)>
<cfset structInsert(local.appStruct, "AccessLevel", permissionLevel, true)>
<cfset structInsert(local.appStruct, "AccessList", permissionList, true)>
<cfset SESSION.AccountInfo = appStruct>
```

Above I just showed fields that are saved in session scope. All values are pulled from query that I did not show. For example `TempPW` is storing temporary password and I do not need to update that since user will be automatically moved to login page once they set their new password. In other situations where they update `email` or `access type` I'm not sure if I should log out user or try to update session scope? Is there any security risk doing it one way or the other? I'm just trying to implement the best practice in my application. Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated, but typically you don't store passwords (any passwords) in session variables.

Comment: @Ageax It's not actual password, just a flag 1 or 0. Users with temporary password are forced to change the password and login again.

Comment: Oh, okay, good :)  I usually name boolean variables with an IsSomething or HasSomething so the type is clear, but that's just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a user's perspective, having to logout and login again sounds less than ideal.

I suggest updating the session scope when the user updates their email or other values.
There should be no difference in security in that, vs requiring a user to logout and login again.

On the page the user updates their email, after you update the values in the database simply override the session variables, for example:

```
<cfset SESSION.AccountInfo.Email = form.email>
<cfset SESSION.AccessLevel = "SOME_NEW_ACCESS_LEVEL">
etc...
```

As a side recommendation, I would stop using `structInsert`, you can simply set the variable and avoid the (extremely small) performance overhead of calling a function. Your same code above could be rewrote as:

```
<cfset local.appStruct = structNew()>
<cfset local.appStruct.SysAdmin = checkUser.SystemAdmin>
<cfset local.appStruct.UserName = checkUser.UserName>
<cfset local.appStruct.AccountID = checkUser.AccountID>
<cfset local.appStruct.Email = checkUser.Email>
<cfset local.appStruct.TempPW = checkUser.TempPassword>
<cfset local.appStruct.AccessType = permissionType>
<cfset local.appStruct.AccessLevel = permissionLevel>
<cfset local.appStruct.AccessList = permissionList>
<cfset SESSION.AccountInfo = appStruct>
```

If, for some reason, you need to preserve the case of the struct keys, you can use array style syntax such as:

```
<cfset local.appStruct = structNew()>
<cfset local.appStruct["SysAdmin"] = checkUser.SystemAdmin>
<cfset local.appStruct["UserName"] = checkUser.UserName>
<cfset local.appStruct["AccountID"] = checkUser.AccountID>
<cfset local.appStruct["Email"] = checkUser.Email>
<cfset local.appStruct["TempPW"] = checkUser.TempPassword>
<cfset local.appStruct["AccessType"] = permissionType>
<cfset local.appStruct["AccessLevel"] = permissionLevel>
<cfset local.appStruct["AccessList"] = permissionList>
<cfset SESSION.AccountInfo = appStruct>
```

You can use `<cfdump` to see the differences between the two structs and how the keys are either all lower case in the first example, or their upper/lower case is preserved in th esecond example.

```
<cfdump var="#local.appStruct#" />
```

Sorry I may be getting off topic, hope it helps.

Comment: So instead of using `structUpdate()` you would recommend dot notation and overwriting previous value? Side note, pretty simple I can update `Username`, `Email`, `PermissionType` and `PermissionLevel` but updating `PermissionList` is not that simple since I build that upon users login. This process requires looping over permissions and setting them in specific group based on credentials. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Ahh, okay, good luck!  Could you possibly move that PermissionList logic to a CFC so that you could call a function such as `<cfset local.appStruct.PermissionList = User.generatePermissionList()>` ?? And, I could be misunderstanding your question, but since `SESSION.AccountInfo.PermissionList` is set on login, it will still exist when you update `SESSION.AccountInfo.Email`, - again, sorry if I misunderstand.

Comment: It will still exist but what I'm saying is if user updates his permissions I have to compare if they are different and then build new list and assign to session scope.

Comment: Or you could also save a lot more typing and use `<cfset local.appStruct = { SysAdmin : checkUser.SystemAdmin , UserName : checkUser.UserName, ... } >`.  My suggestion would be to use cfscript syntax since this is new dev. It's a lot easier to do a lot of things.

Answer (score 2):

This is not intended as an answer but rather as a comment on how to simplify Struct creation.

As I mentioned in the the comment to @sqrl0's answer, with tags you can go with:

```
<cfset local.appStruct = {
    "SysAdmin"    : checkUser.SystemAdmin ,
    "UserName"    : checkUser.UserName ,
    "AccountID"   : checkUser.AccountID ,
    "Email"       : checkUser.Email ,
    "TempPW"      : checkUser.TempPassword ,
    "AccessType"  : permissionType ,
    "AccessLevel" : permissionLevel ,
    "AccessList"  : permissionList
}>
<cfset SESSION.AccountInfo = local.appStruct>
```

Or CFScript: ***NOTE: You don't need to copy the struct to SESSION.AccountInfo. You can just create it there.***

```
<cfscript>
  SESSION.AccountInfo = {
    "SysAdmin"    : checkUser.SystemAdmin ,
    "UserName"    : checkUser.UserName ,
    "AccountID"   : checkUser.AccountID ,
    "Email"       : checkUser.Email ,  
    "TempPW"      : checkUser.TempPassword ,
    "AccessType"  : permissionType ,
    "AccessLevel" : permissionLevel ,
    "AccessList"  : permissionList
  }
</cfscript>
```

Make sure that any variables being overwritten are meant to be that way. That's one of the prime reasons not to use the same variable names for different things. Accidental overwrites will drive you absolutely bonkers when you try to debug.

Comment: Thanks for providing example. I'm little confused on what you are trying to explain in your last comment about overwriting the variables...

Comment: If you have `SESSION.AccountInfo.email` and then create `local.appStruct.email` and copy `appstruct` to `SESSION.AccountInfo`, you will overwrite `SESSION.AccountInfo.email` with `local.appStruct.email`.

Comment: Excellent demonstration of some shorter struct creation @Shawn !